# Bootstrap dropright dropdown doesn't flip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm learning to create side navigation with *dropdown* opening to the right. I'm using `.dropright` class to initiate this behaviour, as said on bootstrap-4 documentation side. However, when using `.dropright`, the `.dropdown-menu` doesn't flip if it is close to the bottom of the viewport, and instead it shows under viewport bottom border, while making the screen scrollable. If i delete `.dropright` flipping works. Can you help me fix this please?

I'm using this project https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar, with this change to the `#sidebar-wrapper`:

```
<div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap </div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Shortcuts</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Overview</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Events</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>

    <div class="btn-group dropright">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-toggle="flip" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropright</button>
        <div class="btn-group dropright">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-toggle="flip" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropright</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Shortcuts</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Overview</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Events</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Profile</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Status</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[example of undesired behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua2Qf.png)

[example of desired behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqfM9.png)